# How to make asynchronous api calls in loop and conditional statements in react js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

```
[
  {
    description: "question value1",
    subjectId: "",
    classId: "",
    image:"",
    answers: [{ description: "option value", isCorrect: false },
    { description: "option value", isCorrect: true }
    ],
  },
  {
    description: "question value2",
    subjectId: "",
    classId: "",
    answers: [{ description: "option value", isCorrect: false },
    { description: "option value", isCorrect: true }
    ],
  },
]
```

I have something like this and now i need to make the post call to api for each question so that once the question is created i get the question ID back and then i can use that ID to create options for that question and if it has image upload the image too and have to wait for each of them to finish how can i do that i really m bad asynchronous progamming, there are sperate API's for creating a question creating a option for the question uploading a image for the question
This what i have tried so far but for some reason its wrong idk

```
    async mapCreatedQuestions(questionId) {
    let token = getCookie(process.env.token);
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("QuestionId", questionId);
    formData.append("QuizId", this.state.quizId);
   await axios
      .post(`api to create a association if question already exists`, formData, {
        headers: {
          authorization: `${TOKEN_TYPE}${token}`,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {})
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error !!!.. association");
        console.log(err);
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      });
  }
  async createOptions(question, questionId) {
    let token = getCookie(process.env.token);
    question.answers.map((option, index) => {
      //options uploaded from here
      console.log("this options are for the question", option);
      if (option.description.length > 0) {
        let formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("Description", option.description);
        formData.append("QuestionId", questionId);
        formData.append("IsCorrect", option.isCorrect);
        axios
          .post(`api to add answers(options)`, formData, {
            headers: {
              authorization: `${TOKEN_TYPE}${token}`,
            },
          })
          .then((response) => {
            console.log("option created", response);
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Error !!!.. In options");
            console.log(err);
            this.setState({ loading: false });
          });
      }
    });
  }
  async questionImageUpload(questionPicture, questionId) {
    let token = getCookie(process.env.token);
    //upload the picture of the question

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("ImageTitle", "quizImage" + questionId);
    formData.append("QuestionId", questionId);
    formData.append("Image", questionPicture);
  await  axios
      .post(`api to upload image`, formData, {
        headers: {
          authorization: `${TOKEN_TYPE}${token}`,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("image uploaded successfully ", response);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(" image upload failed err", err);
        this.setState({ loading: false });
      });
  }
 async createEachQuestion (question){
   let formData = new FormData();
   formData.append("Description", question.description);
   formData.append("QuestionTypeId", question.questionTypeId);
   formData.append("SubjectId", question.subjectId);
  await axios
     .post(`apitocreatequestion`, formData, {
       headers: {
         authorization: `${TOKEN_TYPE}${token}`,
       },
     })
     .then((response) => {
       this.setState({ questionId: response.data.result });
       let questionId = response.data.result;
       if (question.questionPicture.toString().length > 0) {
        this.questionImageUpload(question.questionPicture, questionId);
       }
     })
     .catch((err) => {
       console.log("error in question creationn", err);
     });
      await this.createOptions(question,questionId);
     await this.mapCreatedQuestions(questionId);

 } 
 async mapEachQuestion (){
  console.log("this question will be mapped not created", question);
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("QuestionId", question.questionId);
  formData.append("QuizId", this.state.quizId);
 await axios
    .post(`apitoassociatequestionandquiz`, formData, {
      headers: {
        authorization: `${TOKEN_TYPE}${token}`,
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("question asssociated", response);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log("Error !!!.. association");
      console.log(err);
      this.setState({ loading: false });
    });
 }
  async createQuestion() {
    let token = getCookie(process.env.token);
    this.state.questionList.map((question, index) => {
      if (question.hasOwnProperty("questionId")) {
        //map the existing question id to quiz
        this.mapEachQuestion (question)
      } else {
        this.createEachQuestion (question)
      }
    });
  }

  async createQuiz(quiz) {
    await this.setQuestionList;
    await this.sendQuiz;
    this.setState({ loading: true });
    let formData = new FormData();
    console.log("quiz", quiz);
    console.log("this.state.questionList", this.state.questionList);
    let id = getCookie(process.env.iId);
    formData.append("Description", quiz.Description);
    formData.append("Title", quiz.Title);
    formData.append("TimeinMinute", quiz.TimeInMinute);
    let token = getCookie(process.env.token);
    await axios
      .post(`apitocreatequiz`, formData, {
        headers: {
          authorization: `${TOKEN_TYPE}${token}`,
        },
      })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("quiz created successfully. Response =>", response);
        //setQuizId in state
        this.setState({ quizId: response.data.result });
        
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error !!!.. when creating the quiz");
        console.log(err);
        this.setState({loading:false});
      });
      await this.createQuestion;
      this.setState({loading: false});
  }
```

Comment: Is your problem with rendering, looping or something else? Please elaborate on the problem, share your code and other things that might help

Comment: What have you tried so far, please share that so that someone can help.

Comment: yes i have edited the post can anybody help

Answer (score 1):

API calls are a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that data will be returned *at some point*.

Fortunately async processes have become much easier to deal with recently. You can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to capture the data once it's been resolved.

Your data is already in an array so it becomes much easier.

In this first example you can use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to get the data, and then gather the data.

```js
function mockApi(n) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res(n), 2000);
  });
}

const input = [1, 2, 3, 4];

function getData(input) {

  // Instead of mockApi(el) use `fetch(url)`
  const promises = input.map(el => mockApi(el));
  Promise.all(promises).then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}

getData(input);
```

In this example you can use [`async/await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await):

```
function mockApi(n) {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => res(n), 2000);
  });
}

const input = [1, 2, 3, 4];

async function getData(input) {
  const data = input.map(el => mockApi(el));
  const output = await Promise.all(data);
  console.log(output);
}

getData(input);
```

Comment: could you elaborate according to my code please i have updated the question